# AWS Chime SDK js: the attendee video height is different on chrome and firefox

Tags: html5-video, aws-chime-sdk

i'm working with aws chime sdk js library and implementing the attendee video share feature in an video title layout. Interestingly, I finds that the video height(which is set to auto) is different on chrome and firefox(firefox having larger height than the one shared from chrome).
[image]

let me know how can I achieve all attendee videos should have the same height?